# How to design when there is only one subclass need to be specified using polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Given a base class *Base*, that's say *A*, *B*, *C* extends *Base*.
If there is a specific method *m()* only in *C*. To call *m()* , you should first determine if the given class is type of *C* , one of the way is to use:

```
otherMethod(Base b){
  if(b instanceof C) 
    b.m();
}
```

But I'd like to use:

```
otherMethod(Base b){
  b.m();
}
```

This means I have to pull the *m()* method up to the super class *Base* and only implement it in class *C*. But *m()* has no relation for class *A* and *B* and should not belong to them. This is not intuitive for code readability. So is there a better design of this case to use polymorphism and without non-reasonable method position?

Comment: If `m()` belongs to `C` and not to `Base`, then it should be in `C`; just as `get(int)` belongs to `List` and not to `Collection`. You can always **overload** `otherMethod(Base)` with `otherMethod(C c)`

Comment: What is the use case? Do you iterate over a list of `Base` and try to call `m()` on each of them, iff the type is `C`?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus that's what I am going to do. The Base class is a Shape class, and A B C is different type of shapes. And I want to loop through all shapes to and do something only if the shape is C.

Comment: @ernest_k overload might be a solution I'm looking for. I'll try to design it with overloading, thank you!

Comment: Yeah a use case here would really help us understand what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If a class `C` has any specific method, same should not be part of `Base` class. To call the method `m()`, you will have to check the type of instance using `instanceof` operator and then cast your `Base` class to `C` and then call method `m()` like below

```
otherMethod(Base base){
  If(base instanceof C){
    C c= (C) base;
    c.m();
  }
}
```

Further, as others have already cited out the example of `Collection` and `List`, if your class `C` needs to have specific method, you should create one `interface`, lets say its called `Child` which should extend the `Base` interface. The other 2 classes should implement `Base` interface. And class `C` should implement `Child` interface.

Now, when you are designing `Base` interface, definitely, you won't know what specific methods other classes could implement. Therefore, you should not be calling any specific method in your otherMethod as well.

Comment: There is a mistake in authors understanding. Author is trying to call the method using base class object. Although, its not part of it. It requires casting of object otherwise it will cause ClassCastException.I am only saying this is the only correct way. How am i wrong here?

Comment: @ManishBansal sorry I was tempting to give a quick example and did not notice that, that's my fault. But what I'm looking for is an answer like not using "instanceof". Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use overriding methods. When calling otherMethod() on a Base object, it will call the doThings() defined in Base unless it is an instance of C, which has overloaded the doThings().

```
public class Base {

   public void doThings() {
       // nothing happens
   }

   public void otherMethod() {
       doThings(); // will call method above if instance is Base object, will call method below if C object
   }
}

class C extends Base {

   public void doThings() {
       System.out.println( "Things actually get done" );
   }
}
```

Comment: *****overriding

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java 8 and performance is not an issue (which would be the case if you want to render 10000 shapes at 60fps) then filter the collection.

Assuming a `Collection<Shape> shapes`:

```
shapes.stream()
      .filter(s -> s instanceof C)
      .forEach(c -> ((C)c).m());
```

nb. You should never declare behavior (i.e. methods) in classes or interfaces that have nothing to do with it. In ernest_k's example, don't put `get(int)` in interface `Collection` just because `List` uses it. This keeps the class structure clean and understandable. Instead change the usage of the class structure, either the hard way (with type checking and casting) or by separating different subclasses in different collections (so you don't have to check types).

If you had this:

```
Collection<A> justA;
Collection<B> justB;
Collection<C> justC;
```

then you wouldn't have this problem, but then you would have another (probably worse) problem, that every time you add another subclass (say `D`) you have to change code all over the place, and there is the risk you forget to change it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Don't infect the design further than adding a `Base.visit(IVisitor v) {v.visit(this);}`

```
interface IVisitor {
  void visit(Base b);
}
```

Then write the IVisitor you need (here with the instanceof C)
Of course, you could just use  Consumer  instead of your own visitor interface. I just meant to be clear.